# some advices on deploying Django app to product locally

Tags: django, python-3.x

I want to deploy (production not testing) Django app with PostgreSQL database for my company, however, for security reason I want the app to be on local network and not accessible through the internet. I need some recommendations and advices to achieve that on setup and tools.

Suppose I know `python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

EDIT: I wanted to be accessible by different machine on the same network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use command:

```
python3 manage.py runserver 8080
```

The default bind ip is `127.0.0.1`, it can be only be access from your local network but not from the internet.

Comment: thanks for your effort, this command only accessible for the same machine. I wanted to be accessible by machines on the same network for production use not only testing

Comment: if you gonna use it for production, you should consider use Nginx and serve the urls which is not sensitive, for example, you can config something like `location / { proxypass  http://127.0.0.1:8000/ }`, and you can allow or deny ip range in your nginx settings, please check out this article: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-nginx-access-control-howto/

Answer (score -1):

By default when you will runserver it will run on 127.0.0.1. And that will only be visible to your computer only

You have to do about two changes
First of all get your ip address of your local lan network by ipconfig command(in ubuntu). you can search other command to detect ip of your local lan network on your own

Let say your network ip is 192.168.0.100
Now go to settings.py
change ALLOWED_HOSTS=[] to

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.0.100']
```

Now run

```
python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

It will visible to all your clients connected on that network

They just have to type this url
192.168.0.100:8000
to see the website

Comment: thanks for your effort, is it enough or it's better if I used some web serve (e.g NginX)? because the app works with sensitive data.

Comment: when you will run it on 192.168.0.100 who else can access?

Comment: That is not what ALLOWED_HOSTS does.

Comment: removed that part, Thanks